# socket.io : can a socket IO client emit function register a call back function

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to send a message to the server and at the same time save that message to an array in the client. I wanted to know before i start if socketio.emit takes in a call back, something like this :

```
socket.emit('startRecording', {someData: 'value'}, function (response) {})
```

Answer (score 1):

socket.io does support an ACK callback from sending a message.  It is described [here in the socket.io doc](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketemiteventname-args-ack).  Here's the example of how it would be used from the doc:

```
// client code
socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', (data) => {
  console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
});

// server code
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('ferret', (name, fn) => {
      // send ACK response
      fn('woot');
    });
});
```

If the last argument you pass `.emit()` is a callback, then that callback will be called if/when the server provides an ACK response as show in the example above.  This allows you to use a request/response for a given message where you get a specific response from sending a message.

Comment: @thanus - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.